# @font-face custom icon font only showing unicodes

Tags: css

I'm using a custom icon-font using CSS3's @font-face and in older version of Google Chrome, only the unicodes are showing and are not being replace or rendered in my custom font, which shows the glyphs for those unicodes.

Here is the @font-face syntax that I am using:

```
@font-face{
    font-family:'glyphs';
    src:url('../fonts/glyphs.eot');
    src:url('../fonts/glyphs.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/glyphs.svg#glyphs') format('svg'),
        url('../fonts/glyphs.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/glyphs.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Any idea why the unicodes are showing and not the symbols that are part of the icon-font?

Comment: Did you by chance use Font Squirrel or another font generator to package up the font?

Comment: @Lowkase not font-squirrel. I used the icomoon app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're possibly running into `unicode-range` limitations. As described [here](http://24ways.org/2011/creating-custom-font-stacks-with-unicode-range/) you can define in a `font-face` declaration which Unicode characters are covered. It could very well be that older Chrome versions only replaced Latin characters by default. You should be able to fix this by adding this to your font-face declaration:

```
unicode-range: U+00-FFFF;
```

Having said that, it could very well be that you're only having a local issue. Check in your Chrome settings, under *Advanced Settings*, under *Web Content* click *Customize Fonts*, then at the bottom check the current setting for *Encoding*. Changing its value to "Unicode (UTF-8)" could solve the issue as well.

Comment: Ah, I'll look into that. It is displaying those Unicode's fine just the square boxes, but they're not being replaced by the font's symbols.

Comment: That's why I suspect it's the font encoding being used (the Chrome setting) or the `unicode-range` defaulting to something in the lower ranges (since that would explain higher characters not being shown in the font).

Comment: Okay, I still haven't had time to look into it. I should soon. By latest, Monday.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thank you for letting me know about this. Hopefully it will fix the problem. What should the unicode range be if I am using normal latin alphabet and the symbols U+e00c, U+e00d, U+e00e, and U+e00f and U+e010, U+e011, U+e012, U+e013, U+e014, and U+e015?

Comment: [Here's the full table, enjoy](http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html) ;)

Comment: I see. But, I am confused. How did you get the value for the unicode-range property from that table? What would be the value for unicode-range if I used the Unicode's I mentioned above and how do I get that value from the table. In other words, I'm confused on how to use the table to get the value.

Comment: 00-FFFF is just 'the entire table'  ;)   As for specifics - play with it, it's not a property I use on a daily basis either hehe.

Comment: Ah, I'll use the entire table value, then. Thank you for the help! Doesn't seem like something one would use frequently, anyway thank you!

Comment: Follow the link in my post for a full sample ('as described here').

Answer (score 4):

Try switching the orders of the fonts you are loading. Some browsers, even older version of chrome, load svg fonts in weird / incomplete ways.

Try:

```
@font-face{
    font-family:'glyphs';
    src:url('../fonts/glyphs.eot');
    src:url('../fonts/glyphs.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/glyphs.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/glyphs.ttf') format('truetype');
        url('../fonts/glyphs.svg#glyphs') format('svg'),
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, good point. I heard some browsers render svg fonts in a weird way. But, it doesn't seem to be fixing it.

Answer (score 3):

I may be going out on a limb here, but is it possible that the document displaying the font either a) declares a character encoding other than UTF-8 / UTF-16 (or isn't explicitly declared) or b) the html document is saved in an encoding other than UTF-8 / UTF-16?

A very common problem causing websites to display characters incorrectly is having a different declared character encoding in the HTML than the encoding used to save the HTML document.  Also, the use of characters that are part of either of these encodings can create issues.

Answer (score 2):

You should post the HTML code as well for us to answer better. I'm assuming you are using `data-icon` attribute in HTML. In that case, you should add this code after your font-face css code.

```
[data-icon]:before {
    font-family: 'glyphs';
    content: attr(data-icon);
    speak: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Comment: I'm not using data-icon. I am just applying a class to the container that contains the text / unicodes that has a style of font-family: 'glyphs'; I don't see how that fixes my issue. It seems like a reset with unnecessary styling.

Answer (score 1):

I've had some problems with relative paths, old browsers and font-face declarations in the past: you might want to try with a fixed path (/someFolderInRoot/fonts/glyphs.svg) or a relative path under the css file-path (fonts/glyphs.svg).

Does it all work in a newer version of Chrome and other browsers? 
Chrome installs updates automatically for most users, so perhaps you're making the website backwards compatible for a version nobody uses.

Comment: It right now uses a fixed path. Yes, chrome has auto-update. But the computers in my dorm's computer lab have XP and the version of chrome before auto-update. This is also where the problem is.

Comment: Oh, by fixed do you mean without the up one dir `../` notation.

Comment: by fixed I mean NOT relative, based from the root dir, starting with `/` or with a full path (http://...)

Comment: Oh, okay. I get it. I'll try that and let you know.