# @font-face does not load although all font files are accessible

Tags: html, css

Everything in my web works well except `@font face` in the CSS file.
My web uses 2 fonts which neither of them can be loaded to display. One of them is fontawesome. I both tried to load the font from my server and the fontawesome server, but the result is the same.

I tried to view the page in IE Edge, Firefox and Chrome browser in PC and neither of them worked properly. However, when I tested in iPad Safari, it worked well.

Please be informed that all font files are accessible and my PC can view font in fontawesome.io perfectly. Please kindly advice what is wrong in my code.

Here is the code:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');
  src: url('http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.7.0')             format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0')                  format('woff2'),
       url('http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0')                   format('woff'),
       url('http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0')                    format('truetype'),
       url('http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Here is the result in PC (Font Face is not load):

[image: Font Face Result in PC]

Here is the result in iPad (Font Face is load successfully):

[image: Font Face Result in Mobile]

Comment: What you are seeing on PC are unicodes where the characters are linked to. A similar problem has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284451/font-face-custom-icon-font-only-showing-unicodes.
Make sure that your font files are webfonts, and check the encoding and unicode range your web document, as well as your font files use.

Answer (score 0):

From the png it's imposible to understand the problem. I can tell you to Read well [this link](http://fontawesome.io/get-started/) you could found your solution.

**If Using CSS**
Copy the entire font-awesome directory into your project.
In the `<head>` of your html, reference the location to your font-awesome.min.css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

**Using Sass or Less**
Use this method to customize Font Awesome 4.7.0 using LESS or SASS.

Copy the `font-awesome/` directory into your project.
Open your project's `font-awesome/less/variables.less` or `font-awesome/scss/_variables.scss` and edit the `@fa-font-path` or `$fa-font-path` variable to point to your font directory.
`@fa-font-path: "../font"`;
The font path is relative from your compiled CSS directory.

Comment: Thanks so much, but I think the cause that font face is not load. I'm not sure why :(

Here is the web link.
https://staging2.ipsosinteractive.com/mriweb/mriweb.dll?i.project=S16020040&id=12

Comment: I see the icon in my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

If your website runs via HTTPS protocol and you are trying to load external resources via HTTP - the loading will be blocked by browser.

Second, if the above is not the case - make sure you are loading the fonts with **correct** file path, for example:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

or use bootstrap CDN:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`